# Xamarin 4.2.4 (build 35) error "connection to the layout renderer failed"

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have this error in my first Xamarin android (c#) app when I try to open "layout>main.xaml" file :

"connection to the layout renderer failed".

can anyone help me!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try one of these configurations, as John Miller pointed [here](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/51784/#Comment_51784)

**Windows / Visual Studio 2013 / Xamarin Studio**

Xamarin.Android 4.12.02001 using Android SDK Tools 22.6

Xamarin.Android 4.12.03003 using Android SDK Tools 22.6.2

Xamarin for VS 1.12 (Alpha) using Android SDK Tools 22.6.2

**How do I downgrade my Android SDK Tools?**

If you already updated to 22.6.3, or some other non-compatible version of the SDK tools and Xamarin.Android, you can either upgrade your Xamarin.Android to match the above setups or download an older version of the SDK tools. Here is how you can do that:

You should make a backup of your tools folder that we will replace in the Android SDK directory on your computer. Simply rename the folder to something like tools_backup. That directory is normally installed in a path like this:

C:\Users{USER NAME}\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools

Download the version of SDK tools you need from Google using the links provided below.

[Android SDK Tools 22.6](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22.6-windows.zip)

[Android SDK Tools 22.6.2](http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r22.6.2-windows.zip)

You can change the version number in the actual URL link to another revision if you need it

Once you download the ZIP, extract the tools folder and place it in the Android SDK directory above where you backed up the previous version of the tools folder.

Restart your Visual Studio / Xamarin Studio.

**EDIT:**

Xamarin Studio 4.2.5 has resolved the issue. It needs Android SDK Tools 22.6.3.